# Auto-create google calendar events from multiple sheets in a workbook using a trigger and without creating duplicate events

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-calendar-api

I am woefully ignorant here, so any help is much appreciated. My apps script code is sloppy af and piecemealed together from examples online. I know it is trash and does not account for most of what I need. That's why I'm here. My goal is to auto-populate google calendar events from multiple sheets in a workbook and create a trigger so that anytime content is edited in those cells a new event populates (or the event edited) but repeat events aren't created.

The cells I'd be pulling data from will be the same for each sheet:
C4:C24 (these cells hold the title of the event) and
E4:F24 (these cells hold start date and time and end date and time respectively).

The trigger I have set up is on edit but when I make an edit, duplicate events get created each time, which I do not want.

Any help is incredibly appreciated. Thank you!

```
// function to retrieve data from Sheet and add to Calendar 
function simpleSheetsToCalendar() { 

// get spreadsheet 
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
var eventCal = 
CalendarApp.getCalendarById('actualCalendarId');  
var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("C4:F24").getValues();
for (x=0; x<signups.length;x++)
{
var shift = signups[x];
var task= shift[0];
var startTime = shift[2];
var endTime = shift[3];
eventCal.createEvent(task, startTime, endTime);} }
```

Comment: Can you provide your current script?

Comment: It's embarrassingly inaccurate and doesn't come close to accounting for what I want to do, but yes...edited the post to add it.  What I have kicks back an error, but does populate an event properly; however it also creates duplicate events anytime you make an edit.  It also doesn't factor in creating events from multiple sheets.  Thank you!!!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding your script. From your additional information, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the cells "C4:F24" from multiple sheets in a Google Spreadsheet.

  - The columns "C", "E", and "F" are the event title, start time, and end time, respectively.
- You want to create a new event to a Google Calendar using the retrieved values. At that time, you don't want to create the duplicated event title.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, in order to retrieve all titles of the calendar event, Calendar API is used. So before you use this script, [please enable Calendar API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set `sheetNames` and `calendarId`.

```js
function simpleSheetsToCalendar() {
  var sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet3",,,]; // Please set the sheet names you want to use.
  var calendarId = "###"; // Please set your calendar ID.

  // 1. Retrieve all events from the Calendar and create an object for checking the duplicated titles.
  var events = [];
  var pageToken = "";
  do {
    var res = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {maxResults: 2500, fields: "nextPageToken,items(summary)", pageToken});
    events = events.concat(res.items);
    pageToken = res.nextPageToken;
  } while(pageToken);
  var obj = events.reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e.summary]: true}), {});

  // 2. Retrieve sheets from a Google Spreadsheet and retrieve the values from "C4:F24", and create an object for creating new events.
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values = spreadsheet.getSheets().reduce((o, sheet) => {
    if (!sheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName())) return o;
    var signups = sheet.getRange("C4:F24").getValues();
    signups.forEach(([title,,startTime,endTime]) => {
      if (!obj[title] && title && startTime && endTime && !o[title]) o[title] = {startTime,endTime};
    });
    return o;
  }, {});

  // 3. Create new events.
  var ar = Object.entries(values);
  if (ar.length == 0) return;
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  ar.forEach(([title, {startTime, endTime}]) => eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime));
}
```

- When this script is run, all event titles in the calendar are retrieved, and the values are retrieved from "C4:F24" on the multiple sheets in a Google Spreadsheet. And then, new events are created by checking the duplicated title.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the event title is checked for checking the duplicated events. If you want to check other properties, please modify the above sample script.

#### References:

- [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: thank you SO much!  I think you much pretty much nailed what I want, but I'm clearly still doing something wrong because when I run debugger, everything but calendarId is coming back as undefined.  I enabled CalendarAPI and entered the calendarId and sheetNames.   **Here is a blank version of the gsheet with details on what I'm hoping to do, in case it's helpful to see it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SPx_4ZkdSoWLNeYav_PG0JOec41Ab2yGIs__rVsf4L0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @athombomb Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. At first, can I ask you whether my understanding of your question is correct?

Comment: @athombomb And, I saw your sample Spreadsheet. But unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do. I apologize for my poor English skill. I understood your question as follows. You want to retrieve the values from the cells "C4:F24" from multiple sheets in a Google Spreadsheet. The columns "C", "E", and "F" are the event title, start time, and end time, respectively. You want to create a new event to a Google Calendar using the retrieved values. At that time, you don't want to create the duplicated event title. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @athombomb And from your script of `eventCal.createEvent(task, startTime, endTime)`, I thought that the values of `task, startTime, endTime` are the string and date object and date object. How about this? Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your sample Spreadsheet. Can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your current issue and provide the detail of your goal? By this, I would like to try to understand them.

Comment: Your English skills are fantastic, no need to apologize! You understood what I am going for perfectly, I imagine it's the code I used that threw you off, it is definitely not correct. I updated the sample spreadsheet so it can be edited and you can run a test (if you want). Will that help?  The text in the cells detail what I hope to achieve with the code: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SPx_4ZkdSoWLNeYav_PG0JOec41Ab2yGIs__rVsf4L0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @athombomb Thank you for replying. I understood that my understanding of your question was correct. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your sample Spreadsheet, I cannot still understand what you want to do. Can I ask you about the detail of it? If you can do, can you provide the sample input and output you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand your actual goal.

Comment: @athombomb For example, when the values of the columns "C", "E" and "F" of "C4:F24" are the string and date object and date object, the script works. So I cannot replicate your error of `I'm clearly still doing something wrong because when I run debugger, everything but calendarId is coming back as undefined.`. I apologize for my poor skill. So can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to try to understand it. Unfortunately, I cannot also see your current script using my proposed script. I apologize for this.

Comment: ok, I deleted the instructions in the test sheet to avoid further confusion.  it now just has two test events.  what should populate to a calendar is:  "test event" on 10/10/21 4-6 pm from 'sheet1' and "test event 2" on 10/11/21 11-11:15 am from 'sheet2'. when you run your script on the sample spreadsheet it's not returning any errors?  my original script could have easily been incorrect with the string and date object and date object, but the spreadsheet is a replica.  so whatever script would be correct for the replica, should work. sorry for any confusion my sloppy script created.

Comment: @athombomb Thank you for replying. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I cannot find your current script using my proposed script. I apologize for this. Can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the script for correctly replicating the issue of `I'm clearly still doing something wrong because when I run debugger, everything but calendarId is coming back as undefined.`?

Comment: @athombomb I thought that in order to remove your current issue, it is required to replicate your current issue. So I asked to provide the sample Spreadsheet including the script. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Trust me, it is not due to your poor skill.  I really appreciate your help.  This one is on me.  The script I used where it's presenting the "undefined" issue is the script you provided.  So your script used on the spreadsheet I shared should replicate the issue.

Comment: @athombomb Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still find your current script in your sample Spreadsheet. Because your Spreadsheet doesn't include the script. I apologize for this. And about `The script I used where it's presenting the "undefined" issue is the script you provided.`, in this case, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the script for correctly replicating your current issue? And can you provide the detail of your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @athombomb By the way, when I tested your current sample Spreadsheet using my proposed script, no error occurs. 2 new events are created. And when the script is run again, no events are created because the titles are duplicated. I cannot replicate your issue. I apologize for my poor skill. I'm worried that you might not correctly use my proposed script. So I asked you to provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script to correctly replicate your issue. I apologize for this again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't add script to the shared SS. I'm not sure why. The script I used is what you provided, so if you create a copy of the shared spreadsheet and add the script you wrote to it, it should replicate the issue (again only if you want to!). I appreciate the responses help already.

Comment: @athombomb Thank you for replying. About your replying, unfortunately, I cannot understand it. But when I tested my proposed script for your sample Spreadsheet, no error occurs. 2 new events are created. And when the script is run again, no events are created because the titles are duplicated. I cannot replicate your issue. I apologize for my poor skill again. So, can you provide your current script for replicating your issue?

Comment: @athombomb By the way, you might have directly used my proposed script without modifying `var sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet3",,,];` and `var calendarId = "###";`? Also, I'm worried about this. If my understanding is correct, please modify them for your sample Spreadsheet and test it again.

Comment: well shoot, then I have no idea. those are the only things I did change and update, the sheet names and the ### for my calendarId. If it's working for you, I must have missed something simple. I'll keep messing around with it and see if I can figure out what I did wrong. thank you so much.

Comment: @athombomb In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide your current script for correctly replicating your issue?

Comment: @athombomb By the way, in your sample Spreadsheet, the sheet names are `Sheet 1` and `Sheet 2`. If you modified `sheetNames` to `var sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"];`, no sheets are found. Because `Sheet` and `1` is separated with a space in your sample Spreadsheet. I'm worried about this situation. In your sample Spreadsheet, please modify it to `var sheetNames = ["Sheet 1", "Sheet 2"];` and test it again. Of course, please use the valid calendar ID for `calendarId`.

Comment: yes, thank you! I made sure those matched. thank you again for your time and the help.

Comment: @athombomb Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved from `I made sure those matched.`. If your issue is still not resolved, I have to apologize again. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?